# XCode: How to disable Touchbar simulator from running during test run?

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have a Macbook 15in with touch bar and every time I build or run tests from XCode (Cocoa app), the Touch bar simulator pops up. This is interfering with my UI tests since its blocking the click view. Make it go away! How do I disable it?

Under Window menu, there is Show/Hide Touch bar and I can manually close it but I want to disable it from running completely.

It's driving me nuts and a google search turns up nothing.

Comment: Anybody? Just annoys me? :P

Comment: It's funny, but I'm looking for the way to do the opposite: to show Touch Bar window when running specific UI tests :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

That's old but still... It took me at least an hour to find a solution)

Comment: Yes I mentioned you can Hide/Show the TouchBar from the Window menu but this must be done manually each time. Is there setting via Main.storyboard that you found? I don't have that in my project